# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html

This has been asked many times, I've found many other questions like this. None of which has helped me. I can't find the problem in my code and it's about to drive me insane.

Most answers say that there is a typo on my id name. However, I've changed the id name quite a few times and pasted it to no avail.

```
<div id="room_footer" class="d-block m-za std-border">
<span class="pl10 cur-p" onClick="embedToggle()">
    Click here
</span>
<br/>
<div id"123222" class="w275p h120p ml10 d-inline c-l cur-p">
    <textarea class="w250p h100p"></textarea>
    <p></p>
</div>
 <span class="f-right pr10"><a href="">Click Here</a></span>
</div>
```

Javascript. I've tried this with straight JS and jQuery both. Neither of which work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function embedToggle() {
    var id = "123222";
    var obj = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
    alert(obj);

    if(obj == "none") {
        obj = "inline-block";
    } else {
        obj = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

There is something messed up and I can't find it. I've been working on this for about 2hrs now. Much too long for such a simple stupid mistake. Please help me.

Comment: Invalid ID, ID's cant start with numbers!

Comment: @tymeJV Sure they can

Comment: @Ian -- Technically don't ID's have to start with a letter?

Comment: @tymeJV Not in HTML5 (which I hope we've all migrated to). Try it at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input with a HTML5 doctype

Comment: That was just random things on the keyboard. The actual id name is `id="embedCode"`. Numbers work... at least in Chrome.

Comment: @Ian -- Time to start reading the specs more closely :). Thanks for correcting me on that.

Comment: @tymeJV No problem :) You could look at http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @Ian -- It's almost like you can see what I already have open in my browser :X

Comment: @tymeJV Maybe I can o_0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line should be:

```
<div id="id123222" class="w275p h120p ml10 d-inline c-l cur-p">
```

And you should add a letter to the beginning so that it is valid.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id

UPDATE:

The id is valid for HTML5 per comment from @Ian.

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id"123222"
```

should be

```
<div id="something-123222"
```

Check the comments about ID's not being numbers

Comment: Yeah, that was just a desperation move to try and figure out where the problem was. Random things I hit on the keyboard out of frustration. The whole time I knew it was something stupid, but I just couldn't see it. Thanks.